# passing data to app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class `TouchDrawView` which contains  `NSMutableArray *completeLines;`.
Now, when the application terminates, I want to save this array to file (I know
how to do the saving, I have written it as a `saveArray` method of class `TouchDrawView`).

My problem is, in the `appDelegate`, I want to override say `applicationDidEnterBackground` to call the `saveArray` method on the object of my `TouchDrawView` class to save the array to files as I mentioned.

You see my problem? How do I pass the instance of `TouchDrawView` to the `app delegate`, so that the latter can call `saveArray` method on it? e.g.,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [touchDrawViewObject saveArray]; // how to get this object?

}
```

ps. I am trying to avoid singleton/static data so far, just curious how it could be done otherwise.

Comment: Will there only be one instance of TouchDrawView ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are following the MVC design pattern.  Data should **not** be contained within your view class.

Comment: @trojanfoe: it is a custom view and I am saving lines that it must draw in `drawRect`, where else would I store them...

Comment: You store them in the M (model) bit.

Comment: As @trojanfoe suggests have a model handle the saving. When ever you are finished drawing send it to the model to be processed for saving. If for instance your app crashed applicationDidEnterBackground: won't be called but using the model method would have allowed you to already save the drawn data.

Comment: @sbarow: Even if I use a model for saving, I still need to access the right instance of the model from the app delegate, to call saveMethod on it

Comment: No you don't, once you are finished drawing you send the data to your model to be saved. You are not worrying about whether the application is going into the background or not. You are watching for changes in your data such as your drawings and then saving the most recent changes.

Comment: How can you avoid singleton if UIApplication instance is already a singleton?

Comment: @sbarow: yes but my goal was to do the save during app exit (this is an exercise also, and that's why).

Comment: You posted something earlier where you could reference the view from your rootViewController. I think that is fine. Otherwise go with Bob Vork's answer. Just create a save method in your viewController, that will be called when the application goes into the background.

Comment: @sbarow: Hi sbarow, yes indeed either what I posted before is fine, or I can go with Bob Vork's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without a connection to your appDelegate by letting TouchDrawView observe the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification. That fires when the app enters the background.

You might not want to have different save methods all over you app, but that depends the way  your app is built.

Example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(saveMethod:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```